# curl: pass a named parameter from stdin

Tags: bash, curl

I have a web service that expects some parameters. I want to pass one of these parameters (named "data") to curl via stdin.
I tried

```
echo -n "some data" | curl -d  x="foo" -d y="bar" -d data=@- "http://somewhere"
```

which doesn't work, as the value of data then is "@-" instead of "some data".

Is it possible to use the @ in curl to associate the input from stdin with a specific parameter?

edit: My goal is to chain multiples web services so the data I pass will be the output of another curl call.

Comment: Where do you run `curl`? And how do you produce "some data"? Do you get it from a file?

Comment: I added the info to my question

Comment: If your OS supports it, you can use `/dev/stdin` as the file name instead of `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not possible?

```
curl -d  x="foo" -d y="bar" -d data="@some data" "http://somewhere"
```

Or

```
curl -d  x="foo" -d y="bar" -d data="@$(echo "some data")" "http://somewhere"
```

`echo "some data"` can be another command or file input: `$(<somefile)`.

Comment: Thank you! The second one is what i was looking for.

Comment: Why is the `@` needed? You're just passing a string now, not using standard input at all.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure how the OP actually uses it but I just assumed `-` to be presentation of the input, not including `@`. `-` represents input in many applications. Either way it's pretty obvious that it can be omitted.

Comment: I would say it *must* be omitted; "some data" and `$(...)` are just strings now, not file names.

Comment: @chepner I'd consider the change when the OP confirms that `@` is truly unnecessary. I notice the difference when I posted this and I was open to be corrected but the answer was confirmed anyway. Well with our conversation he/she would probably notice it.

Answer (score 11):

**Use `-d @-`**

E.g.:

```
echo '{"text": "Hello **world**!"}' | curl -d @- https://api.github.com/markdown
```

Output:

```
<p>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>
```

Comment: How does `@-` work here? Is it a bash feature?

Comment: @Esteban it's just curl-specific magic, `man curl` mentions it under `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also save your data in a variable and then use it like this:

```
VAR="some data"; curl -d  x="foo" -d y="bar" -d data=$VAR "http://somewhere"
```