# How do I pass the tail of a log file to a command?

Tags: bash, tail

I have quite a few long-running processes and I use this command to text me at various points throughout a script and to let me know when something has completed:

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=<PHONE NUMBER> -d "message=Doneskiiz"
```

Instead of this basic message I would like to include the tail of a log file in the message so that I can see the last few lines to know if it was successful and to peek at the result.  If possible I'd like current time included (or in a second message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

a) execute "date" to retrieve current date

b) execute "tail -n nnn" to retrieve "nnn" last lines of log file

c) execute "curl" with "--data-binary @file" or "--data-binary @-" or "-F field=@filename" to post previous information.

you can see a similar example at [curl: pass a named parameter from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056611/curl-pass-a-named-parameter-from-stdin):

```
tail -n 20 my.log | curl -d date="$(date)" -d number="555123" -F log=@- "http://somewhere"
```

Comment: Could you include the rest of the line and show how the output of tail ends up in "message=<TAIL OUTPUT>"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it something that you can do with tail and pipes, but it something that you can do with inotify library.

take a look to iwatch, that can fires an event when your file is modified and run your script.

Read this.

http://arkanis.de/weblog/2014-02-16-iwatch-run-a-command-when-a-file-changes